# How to work with 1 array with few methods

Tags: c++, class, methods, struct

I have Multidimensional array in my struct i want to work with this array using few methods, i think i should use double pointer but i have no idea how to do it

```
struct generator {
    char r[26][max];

        void set();
    void display();
};

void generator::set() {
    char *tab = new char[max];
    int k = 0;

    cin >> tab;

    while (tab[k] != '\0') {    
        r[0][k] = tab[k];
        k++;
}
void generator::display(){
    cout << r[0][1];    // should display first letter of string
}
```

Comment: The comment "should display first letter of string" is wrong, as you display the *second* element. Besides that (and the uncompilable code), what problem you have? What is your question? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Comment: Prefer `std::string` to raw `char*`. and possibly `std::vector<std::string>` for `r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

> ```
>  cout << r[0][1];    // should display first letter of string
> ```

the comment is wrong, that displays the *second* letter, first letter is at index 0

---

Adding enough definitions and missing '}' to compile and execute :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define max 10

struct generator {
  char r[26][max];

  void set();
  void display();
};

void generator::set() {
  char *tab = new char[max];
  int k = 0;

  cin >> tab;

  while (tab[k] != '\0') {    
    r[0][k] = tab[k];
    k++;
  }
}

void generator::display(){
  cout << r[0][1];    // should display first letter of string
}

int main()
{
  generator g;
  g.set();
  g.display();
  cout << endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra g.cc
vxl15036 /tmp % ./a.out
aze
z
```

Comment: @NoobXDDD because you missed to flush the output , look my answer, I use `cout << endl;` in _main_ for that